# Change Div Class on click takes multiple clicks before it works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I used the methods in this question:
[change div class onclick on another div, and change back on body click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360764/change-div-class-onclick-on-another-div-and-change-back-on-body-click)

So here's my jQuery function:

```
jQuery('.checkbox_wrapper').on('click', function(e){
   jQuery(this).parent()
   .toggleClass('not_selected')
   .toggleClass('selected'); 
});
```

However it doesn't seem to be working properly. It takes multiple clicks before the class changes.

See my jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/7A3vw/

I cut it down to the bare essentials thinking it might be conflicting javascript, but even with the single function it takes multiple clicks before the class actually changes. Because the production environment has 1 click toggle a hidden checkbox, multiple clicks is not reasonable.

Could someone help me figure out what's causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guest you need the checkbox checked together with the toggling of your div.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.checkbox_wrapper').on('click', function(e){ 
       var checked = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(":checked");
       if(checked){
        jQuery(this).parent().addClass('selected').removeClass('not_selected');
       }else{
        jQuery(this).parent().addClass('not_selected').removeClass('selected');
       }                        
    });
});
```

Comment: This may be exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

The click function fires twice, once for the image, and once for the input, as both will bubble to the parent element, and firing twice reverts the classes again ([**proof**](http://jsfiddle.net/7A3vw/4/)).

Just target the image instead, as that is what you're really trying to click, not the parent :

```
jQuery('.deck_card img').on('click', function (e) {
    jQuery(this).closest('div').parent().toggleClass('not_selected selected')
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7A3vw/2/)

Comment: This creates the desired effect on the jsfiddle. However I notice it causes some strange effects in the actual environment. It seems this adds the classes to the checkbox_wrapper div, rather than changing the class of the parent div. The resulting effect is having the image get the not_selected and selected css at the same time. They each reduce image size to 10%, so the image becomes 1%.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is triggering click event twice.  So use [**`.preventDefault()`**](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

This makes the default action of the event will not be triggered.

```
$('.checkbox_wrapper').on('click', function(e){
    $(this).parent()
    .toggleClass('not_selected')
    .toggleClass('selected');
    e.preventDefault();  // prevent the default action to be 
});                      // triggered for next time
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7A3vw/5/)

Comment: This works, except it disables the other javascript functions I mentioned.

Comment: "disables the other javascript functions" can you explain little more?

Comment: When the e.preventDefault(); is added, the deck size stays at 0/100 even when the images are clicked.

Comment: @Jared you're having both `click` and `change` for checkbox.  That is bad.  we need to cleanup the code.

Comment: Hmm, it currently works as this: http://jsfiddle.net/7A3vw/7/
It works, but I do agree that the code needs to be cleaned up and optimized. Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
jQuery(document).on("click",'.checkbox_wrapper', function(e){
   jQuery(this).parent()
   .toggleClass('not_selected')
   .toggleClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: I would normally put this function inside a
  jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
Will this cause conflicts? I'm sorry I'm still fairly new to jquery.

Comment: Also, your method still has the issue. It requires a doubleclick to change class, rather than the desired single click.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Clicks are getting triggered because you are using class selector. You need to use `not` to exclude extra elements :

```
jQuery("div.checkbox_wrapper :not('div.checkboxdiv')").on('click', function(e){
    jQuery(this).parent()
    .toggleClass('not_selected selected')

});
```

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/injulkarnilesh/7A3vw/8/).